# Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

can any one help me i wasted 3days in order to fixe this problems without result
I followed the advice in this[Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404916/failed-to-start-component-standardenginecatalina-standardhostlocalhost-stan) answer and deleted the folder tmp0. but I still get the same error.
the error message ;

```
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/WebServiceClientNote]]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:816)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/WebServiceClientNote]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        ... 6 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lmetier/Operation;
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2575)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1908)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:270)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:65)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:403)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:879)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBContextConfig.configureStart(OpenEJBContextConfig.java:115)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:374)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5378)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 6 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: metier.Operation
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.LazyStopWebappClassLoader.loadClass(LazyStopWebappClassLoader.java:129)
        ... 21 more

    Jan 24, 2015 7:19:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
    SEVERE: A child container failed during start
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:739)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:689)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:321)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:816)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 6 more

    Jan 24, 2015 7:19:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
    SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
    org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:689)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:321)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:739)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 7 more
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 9 more
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 11 more

    Jan 24, 2015 7:19:40 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
    INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
    Jan 24, 2015 7:19:40 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
    INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
    Jan 24, 2015 7:19:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
    INFO: Stopping service Catalina
    Jan 24, 2015 7:19:40 PM org.apache.openejb.server.SimpleServiceManager stop
    INFO: Stopping server services
    Jan 24, 2015 7:19:40 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler destroyApplication
    INFO: Undeploying app: C:\Users\ARAYME.DREAD\workspace\J2EEWorkspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\WebServiceClientNote
    Jan 24, 2015 7:19:40 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler destroyApplication
    INFO: Undeploying app: openejb
    Jan 24, 2015 7:19:40 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler destroyApplication
    INFO: Undeploying app: C:\Users\ARAYME.DREAD\workspace\J2EEWorkspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\ROOT
    Jan 24, 2015 7:19:40 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler destroyApplication
    INFO: Undeploying app: C:\Users\ARAYME.DREAD\workspace\J2EEWorkspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\WebServiceNote
    Jan 24, 2015 7:19:40 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
    SEVERE: The web application [/WebServiceNote] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.apache.axiom.util.UIDGenerator$1] (value [org.apache.axiom.util.UIDGenerator$1@4c163e3]) and a value of type [long[]] (value [[J@4a8355dd]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
    Jan 24, 2015 7:19:40 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler destroyResource
    INFO: Closing DataSource: My DataSource
    Jan 24, 2015 7:19:40 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler destroyResource
    INFO: Closing DataSource: My Unmanaged DataSource
    Jan 24, 2015 7:19:40 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
    INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
    Jan 24, 2015 7:19:40 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
    INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
```

Comment: Can you post your pom file, if you are using maven.